# How to deal with the case that $f(z_0)=0$ for some $z_0\in C_R$?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]
[image]

In the content labeled by red box, if $f(z_0)=0$ for some $z_0\in C_R$, where $C_R$ denotes the circle of radius $R$ centered at origin, how to deal with it?

Comment: An entire function which vanishes on a circle is identically zero and growth estimates are trivial.

Comment: @T.Bongers Sorry, that was not my mind, I have changed my question.

Comment: zeroes are isolated so for any $R$ you can find $\epsilon>0$ s.t. the function has no zeroes on any circle with radius strictly between $R$ and $R+/-\epsilon$ and then, for example, you can let $\epsilon$ go to zero; or you can just ignore the radiuses where the function has zeroes as they are at most countable, so negligible anyway